# Implementing Foldable for a user defined version of Vect with flipped type parameters

Tags: idris

I have defined my own Vect data type as follows

```
data MyVect : (n : Nat) -> (t : Type) -> Type where
  Nil  : MyVect Z t
  (::) : (x : t) -> (xs : MyVect n t) -> MyVect (S n) t
```

And then started to implement the Foldable interface for the data type

```
Foldable MyVect where
  foldr = ?res2
```

However when reloading the file, Idris complaints

```
When checking argument t to type constructor Prelude.Foldable.Foldable:
        Type mismatch between
                Nat -> Type -> Type (Type of MyVect)
        and
                Type -> Type (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        Nat
                and
                        TypeUnification failure
```

After scratching my head a bit, I guessed that I could obey Idris demands for the type constructor by writing

```
Foldable (MyVect n) where
  foldr = ?res2
```

Then I started to think "what if I had defined MyVect with the type parameters flipped?..."

```
data MyVect : (t : Type) -> (n : Nat) -> Type where
  Nil  : MyVect t Z
  (::) : (x : t) -> (xs : MyVect t n) -> MyVect t (S n)
```

**Is it possible to implement the Foldable interface for this 'parameter-flipped' version of `MyVect`? (and how?)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source of type errors you see is in type of `Foldable`:

```
Idris> :t Foldable 
Foldable : (Type -> Type) -> Type
```

Whereas your first version of `MyVect` has type:

```
Idris> :t MyVect 
MyVect : Nat -> Type -> Type
```

and second one has:

```
Idris> :t MyVect 
MyVect : Type -> Nat -> Type
```

You're right that you can partially apply types as you can do with plain old functions.

Thus `Foldable (MyVect n)` works because `MyVect n` has type `Type -> Type` which is exactly what `Foldable` interface wants.

After we convinced ourselves that types behaves like functions you can come up with flipped type aliases for `MyVect` and everything will work:

```
FlippedVect : Nat -> Type -> Type
FlippedVect n t = MyVect t n

Foldable (FlippedVect n) where
```

You can also use already defined functions to implement similar stuff:

```
Idris> :t flip
flip : (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
Idris> :t flip MyVect
flip MyVect : Nat -> Type -> Type
```

And now you can write:

```
Foldable (flip MyVect n) where
```

You can even define instance for anonymous functions. Here is complete version:

```
Foldable (\a => MyVect a n) where
  foldr f z Nil = z
  foldr {n=S k} f z (x :: xs) = x `f` foldr {t=\a => MyVect a k} f z xs

  foldl = believe_me  -- i'm on Idris-0.12.3, I got type errors for `foldl`
                      -- but you can implement it in the same way
```

After writing all that information to teach you how to do it I should say that under any circumstances you definitely shouldn't do it.

Comment: Not sure how this worked on 0.12.3, but on 1.0 as soon as you define `FlippedVect` you get an "Implementation arguments must be type or data constructors" error for everything from there on.

Comment: @AlexanderGryzlov Personally, I agree, that allowing definition of interfaces for anything that is not a data or type constructor is bad. Didn't check it for `1.0` but I glad if it's so :)